# ajax tab container not displaying with ucPageBuilder:PageHost

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, ektron

How can I create a tab panel series to be used interactively on a pagebuilder layout?
I am using Ektron CMS400 version 7.66.  This code seem to keep my tab from showing on the page:(ucPageBuilder:PageHost ID="ucPageHost1" runat="server" />)
Thanks.

Comment: you may get a quicker response posting it to the Ektron forums: http://dev.ektron.com

Their support team monitors these forums and posts responses to them.